# If $x'B'Bx=0$, prove that $x=0$, given $B$ is non-singular and of order $n$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried with $x'B'Bx= (Bx)'Bx=0$, now all the terms of $Bx$ is zero. But can't conclude from that $x$ is $0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answers, mark one as accepted to let other people know that you are happy. If not, please add a comment what is still unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reformulate the problem to 
$$x'B'Bx= 0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow(Bx)'Bx=0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow ||Bx||=0$$

Now, as you know that $B$ is not singular, you can conclude
$$||Bx||=0 \Rightarrow ||x||=0$$

Comment: I could not understand the last line. ||Bx||=0, then is there any proof that ||x|| will be 0

Comment: @saratsindhu If $B$ is nonsingular, then it has a trivial null space, hence the only $x$ satisfying $Bx=0$ is $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks, got it.

Answer (score 1):

If $Bx=0$ and $B$ is invertible, then $x=B^{-1}Bx=0.$

Comment: Where do you get, Bx is zero.

Comment: @saratsindhu You yourself got it in the OP: "all the terms of $Bx$ is zero..."